# When does a morphism from variety over another variety descend to a morphism from the base variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have a morphism of varieties $f:W\times \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1$, where $W$ is a curve. I have an etale cover $p:W \to V$. Suppose that the map $f(w_0,\cdot)=f(w_1,\cdot)$ for all $w_0,w_1\in p^{-1}(t_0)$ for any $t_0\in V$ such that there is an induced set map $\tilde{f}:V \times \mathbb{P}_1 \to \mathbb{P}_1$. Can I conclude that $\tilde{f}$ is a morphism?

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the answer should be negative. Indeed, let $k$ be your ground field and $l$ be a finite separable extension, set $W = \mathbb{P}^1_l$ and $V = \mathbb{P}^1_k$ with the obvious morphism. Let furthermore $a \in \mathbb{P}^1_k$ be an $l$-rational point which is not $k$-rational. Then the map 
$$
f: W \times \mathbb{P}^1_k = \mathbb{P}^1_l \times \mathbb{P}^1_k \to \mathbb{P}^1_l \to Spec(l) \to a \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1_k
$$
which sends everything to $a$ (and thus satisfies your set-theoretic condition) does not descend to a map $V \times \mathbb{P}^1_k \to \mathbb{P}^1_k$ since the left hand variety has a $k$-rational point.

NB: This example somewhat depends on the definition of variety you want to use (e.g. if you want them to be geometrically connected or perhaps even to have algebraically closed base fields it breaks down) so it would be nice if you could supplement the definition you are using.